# Full Node Not Taking Incoming Connections

Tags: full-node

I set up an RPi3 with Bitcoin full node 13.2. It is running Raspbian the latest version and is up to date.

My router has a static IP on the public internet. My RPi3 is behind NAT.

I configured my router to port forward 8333 to my RPi3.

The RPi3 is pretty much stock, so I don't think there is a firewall running. If there is I don't know about it or how to configure it.

The bitnodes site says my RPi3 is not accepting incoming connections.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your node respond to RPC commands? Does it have outgoing connections?

Comment: try to use 'netcat' from another machine connected to the internet. You must know your routers IP, and then try: $ nc <your_router-ip> 8333 - see if it replies. You can use netcat against webservers in the internet with IP address and port 80, to get a bit familiar. This will tell you if your port is really open or not. Some network skills and experience is beneficial :-)

Comment: Are you familiar with Linux/Debian? Know how to search for processes, that might run a firewall?

Comment: I went to a port scanner and it said port 8333 was replying, but when I went to the bitcoin node testing site it said it wasn't responding. Maybe it is because the blockchain is not downloaded yet?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no firewall running.